# groupBy query with nodejs ravendb client

Tags: node.js, typescript, ravendb

I am trying to perform `groupBy` query on ravendb, using [nodejs-ravendb-client](https://github.com/ravendb/ravendb-nodejs-client)!

```
const apmts = await session.query<Appointment>({ collection: "Appointments" })
      .statistics(s => (stats = s))
      .groupBy("client.name").all();
```

facing this error on typescript compile

```
Property 'all' does not exist on type 'IGroupByDocumentQuery<Appointment>'.ts(2339)
```

Any help here?

Comment: Shouldn't `groupBy` apply to the query, i.e. _before_ getting the `statistics`?

Answer (score 4):

Document query's `groupBy()` method returns an object of type [`IGroupByDocumentQuery`](https://github.com/ravendb/ravendb-nodejs-client/blob/v4.1/src/Documents/Session/IGroupByDocumentQuery.ts)
As you can see it does not have `all()` method.

You can use `selectKey()`, `selectCount()` or `selectSum()` for aggregation and then chain it with `all()`. E.g.:

```
const { GroupByField } = require("ravendb");

const orders = await session.query({ collection: "Orders" })
    .groupBy("ShipTo.Country")
    .selectKey("ShipTo.Country", "Country")
    .selectSum(new GroupByField("Lines[].Quantity", "OrderedQuantity"))
    .all();
```

For more details and examples please refer to [official documentation](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.1/nodejs/client-api/session/querying/how-to-perform-group-by-query):